# Are there any available tools to implement Jellium models?

Tags: density-functional-theory, potential-energy-surface, metals

I want to solve a Jellium-DFT like problem. Does any of the self-consistent/DFT software packages available allow to solve for the case of a Jellium configuration (no lattice)?

If not I would like to find a hand-on solution to a similar problem. I want to understand how to apply Kohn-Sham equations to a metal surface. I understand the equations but I would like to understand the ansatz and the numerical methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GPAW density functional theory code has a jellium mode (tutorials [here](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/tutorialsexercises/electrostatics/jellium/jellium.html)). There is, e.g., a [JelliumSlab](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/_modules/gpaw/jellium.html#JelliumSlab) class, where the charge neutralizing jellium background does not extend over all space, but is confined to a slab to model jellium surfaces.